# What has happened to Ant Design? Deleted from GitHub

Tags: reactjs, antd

Has Ant Design project been deleted?
They were one of the biggest opensource frontend framework for React.

- their project on github is returning 404: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/
- their website is broken: https://ant.design/
- they are still available on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd

Comment: Seems like they are still available on: https://gitee.com/ant-design/ant-design . Could be they are trying to leave github for the Chinese alternative?

Comment: Looks like they have migrated https://ant-design.gitee.io/

Comment: It's weird for such a huge project to just leave Github without notice..

Comment: If this is so, its quite unprofessional from their side. All the issue tracking, PR's and such are linked to the github "version". You can't even browse their changelog properly(at https://ant-design.gitee.io/) as not a single link on the page actually leads to a valid resource.

Comment: Seems like Ant Design wasn't the only repo moved over to Gitee. I can also see [Chemex](https://gitee.com/celaraze/chemex) http://chemex.it/ and a couple of other repos gone from Github.

Comment: https://github.com/ant-design/pro-components/issues/1904 Some discussions can be found in one of their other repo's on GitHub.

Comment: Ant design Vue is still live at https://2x.antdv.com/

Comment: "still available on NPM" - unless you know that the code is uncompromised, **do NOT blindly use it**. While I don't know how NPM works, it's potentially possible that it was removed there too and *someone else* uploaded *something* with the same name. (Which may be exactly the same thing, *mostly* the same thing (e.g. with a backdoor added somewhere), or something completely different...) Be very *very* careful (use a known-good local copy if you can) until this is resolved, and maybe use this as an opportunity to review how much of a mess a hostile package would be able create for you.

Comment: @nobody How can you write "while I dont know how NPM works" with such bold statement?

Comment: @LukášGiboVaic The majority of package managers do not protect against hostile name reuse _at all_, so a priori it's unlikely (but not impossible) that NPM does. (Hence the "I don't know NPM details caveat.) Even if NPM does, it's possible that the means of upload for this package were also compromised and thus the code was changed anyway. (So even if that particular fault doesn't apply you should still be careful, hence a warning in spite of uncertainty to counter the blithe  mood of the OP.)

Comment: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design repo is back.

Comment: @nobody most reasonably big packages have 2 factor authentication for releases, while Iam not saying its impossible, Iam saying its strange to say something like this and say, "I dont know how it works" in same sentense

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to a Twitter post by Ant Design:

> Ant Design GitHub reprository disppears without known reason, we are
> looking into it and seeking recover help from @github @GitHubHelp

https://twitter.com/AntDesignUI/status/1361150625505927168

PD: I'm also the mantainer

Answer (score 12):

There is a lot of speculation:

For now, you can check the mirror for the repo [here](https://gitee.com/ant-design/ant-design)<strike>, and the docs [here](https://ant-design.gitee.io/docs/react/introduce).</strike>

Update:

Seems the site is online again [ant.design](https://ant.design/)

Take also in mind @yesmek's [comment](https://github.com/ant-design/pro-components/issues/1904#issuecomment-778880352) (antd design maintainer) on GitHub:

> We are investigating the cause of the problem.

And his [response](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/ljt54q/ant_design_library_gone/gnhjaz6?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) in Reddit as well:

> Gov owned repo ?
>
> Maintainer of ant-design/ant-design here, it's not true, we are investigating the cause of the problem.

We're all in panic, maybe we have too many dependencies on this project, just go and take some coffee and lets wait this valentine's day ends pretty well, for code lovers as all of us.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like it was hacked and removed from github.[Twitter screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIjHB.png)

Answer (score 2):

As for as I know, they're not moving to Gitee (Ant Design is about dozens of repositories). It seems to be hacked and they're investigating this with GitHub.

Answer (score -1):

they moved from github to gitee:

https://gitee.com/ant-design/ant-design

Comment: This looks like a mirror repo on gitee rather than an active repo. Hopefully we'll know soon

Comment: https://twitter.com/AntDesignUI/status/1361150625505927168

Answer (score -3):

Seems like the whole repo has been moved from GitHub to gitee an alternative to github based in china.

New URL for antd repo: (posibly a mirror but not official comments about it)
https://gitee.com/ant-design/ant-design

Documentation:
https://ant-design.gitee.io/docs/react/introduce

Comment: https://twitter.com/AntDesignUI/status/1361150625505927168